# Have div and span based on the number of elements

Tags: javascript, html

My intention is to create `class="dot"` based on the number of elements in the array called count, then use the following for loop:

`for(var i = 0; i < count.length; i++)`

So what I want to get is a single `<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>` where the currentSlide argument is automatically updated based on the for loop, therefore having i in place of 1,2,3 etc.

Is it possible to do this? Can you help me? I'm new to html and javascript.

```js
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

var count = ['img1','img2','img3','img4']
</script>
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work by using [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
//showSlides(slideIndex);

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

var count = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4']
for (var i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML += `
 <span class="dot" onclick=currentSlide(${i})></span> 
 `
}
console.log(document.body.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <!--
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
   -->
</div>
```

OR:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
//showSlides(slideIndex);

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

var count = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4']
for (var i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
document.body.innerHTML += `
 <span class="dot" onclick=currentSlide(${i})></span> 
 `
}
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('span'))
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center">

</div>
```

Comment: Please never use var, there is let and const for that.

Comment: @Gamedroit, it is not pretty a big deal, I am just showing the OP how to deal with it. Also, documentation states that `In Javascript, it doesn't matter how many times you use the keyword “var”`, so it won't be a big problem, but thanks for telling that.

Comment: In which documentation? If it was published a long time ago then it doesn't count anymore, the language has evolved a lot. 

https://javascript.info/

https://phoenix35.js.org/

Comment: @Gamedroit, I don't want to start a argument with you. No value. I directly copy the code from OP's snnipet and OP  use `var`. Also, in term of using which one, each person will have personally opinion.

Comment: @James `currentSlide(${i})` goes without quotes? Moreover, `<div style="text-align:center">` why do you put it aside?

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a, you doesn't need the quotes for template literal, check the documentation I provided. Also, what does `<div style="text-align:center"> why do you put it aside?` mean? You have this in your orignial code. If you means it doesn't display console, I updated the code to let you see it do display the result you want:)

Comment: I meant this: since `<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"> </span>` is in `<div style = "text-align: center">`, as you did it still continues to be in `div`? I hope I have been clearer, I am a beginner with these things

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a, yes it will always inside and become the child element of  `<div style = "text-align: center">`, since your question states that you want to create 3 child element of `<div style = "text-align: center">`, if you don't want to do that, just change it to `document.body.innerHTML`

Comment: yes that's right, I have to create 3 child elements of `<div style = "text-align: center">`. Without deleting your answer above, you can add the code of how to change it in `document.body.innerHTML`? Just out of curiosity, to learn better.

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a, update the code just now:)

Comment: @James Hi James, since I tried but I am a beginner and therefore I still have problems, can you help me with this question? You are special in explaining the arguments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70804784/create-divs-and-divs-in-other-divs-with-img-based-on-the-number-of-elements-in-a

Comment: @a_l_e_x, no problem, just post an answer. Check if it works for you and let me know!