# create divs and divs in other divs with img based on the number of elements in an array

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array with three elements.

I need to create a unique `<div class = "mySlides fade">` for each element of the array, so for each image, with `div class = "numbertext"` changing for each element (so for the first element `1/3`, for the second `2/3` and so on), `img src` which automatically takes the name of the images.

Then using a for loop on length dev create the div present below (I repeat a single div which then changes automatically when the i of the for takes its value).

`for(var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++)` --> this is to iterate through the array

`document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = myArr[i]` --> this to "fetch" the names of the images

```js
var  myArr = ['img_nature_wide.jpg','img_snow_wide.jpg','img_mountains_wide']
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

</div>
```

My problem is in "juggling" the set of divs with img

Sorry if I ask this, but unfortunately I'm new to programming

**CODE ADDED**

suppose besides that div I put above, I also have the div as put in the code below.

What should I do if I have a code made in the following way?

```html
//this is what i put already
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
</div>

</div>
<br>

// this is the new div
<div>
  <span class="arrow" onclick="myFunction(i)"></span>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one using [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and `for` loop.

```js
var myArr = ['img_nature_wide.jpg', 'img_snow_wide.jpg', 'img_mountains_wide']
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  document.querySelector('.slideshow-container').innerHTML += `
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">${i+1} / 3</div>
      <img src="${myArr[i]}" style="width:100%">
    </div>
 `
 document.querySelector('#final').innerHTML +=`
 <span class="arrow" onclick="myFunction(${i})"></span> 
`
}
console.log(document.body.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div id='final'>
  <span class="arrow" onclick="myFunction(i)"></span>  
</div>
```

Comment: as soon as I try I'll let you know. For the moment I thank you infinitely. Since I have several divs in my program, just put the class name of the corresponding div in the querySelector?

Comment: @a_l_e_x, the three <div> has already created and will apeared in the body, if you want to modify them yes, just put their classname in the querySelectorAll

Comment: Can you see the above updated question (CODE ADDED) to understand better please?

Comment: @a_l_e_x, so what is your attempt in the new code? You want to  insert `<div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div><img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg"style="width:100%">` to every `<div class="mySlides fade">
</div>`?

Comment: no I would like to know how to use the selector with the last div added in the above updated answer, ie `<div>
  <span class="arrow" onclick="myFunction(i)"></span>  
</div>` that is, the one outside of `slideshow-container`

Comment: @a_l_e_x, update the answer. Not sure if that is the answer you are looking for

Comment: I would like to have both divs in the for loop. Maybe now I've been clearer., ie ```document.querySelector('.slideshow-container').innerHTML += `
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">${i+1} / 3</div>
      <img src="${myArr[i]}" style="width:100%">
    </div>
 ```  and  ```document.querySelector('div').lastElementChild.innerHTML +=`
 <span class="arrow" onclick="myFunction(${i})"></span> ```.  Why do you use querySelector ('div'). LastElementChild? Is the class name wrong in querySelector? And why do you use lastElementChild?

Comment: @a_l_e_x, I finally gather all your info you need in the code. Check it now. I use `LastElementChild` to select the last `div` in order to not confuse you, I remove it and assign an id instead:)

Comment: OK perfect. Last thing. But to create the divs do I have to use a createElement? or is there no need?

Comment: @a_l_e_x, you could use `createElement`, but in this situation I would highly suggest you not to do it  (since you have assign class, appenchild , textContent) which is too messy. But using the template literal, you are doing the same thing with `creaetElement` but you just directly write html which save your time!

Comment: @a_l_e_x, does your problem being solved?

Comment: I understand, thank you so much and thank you for your patience. Yes it was exactly what I wanted, I haven't tried it yet because I'm out, but as soon as I try it I'll let you know. Meanwhile, I evaluate the answer. Thanks again. You are special in explaining things.

Comment: Can you please help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70833454/i-cant-get-the-actual-number-of-elements

Comment: @a_l_e_x, I check the question, I first need to see how the api look like, but the link you put there is invalid.\

Comment: it's like this:(the one with id equal to 123456): `{"Item":{"marca":"Love","titolo":"You will be missed indefinitely","id":"123456","immagine":"ind.jpg","data":"27/11/2021"}}` .. I notice that URL1s are shown more than 4 times.

Comment: @a_l_e_x, post an answer, check if it works!